# Angular.js and google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am using angular.js to make a selected part of my page visible. The layout looks like this

```
+----------+
|navigation|
+----------+
|content   |
|          |
+----------+
```

When ever an item in navigation is clicked different content is made visible using "ng-hide" directive. In html the page looks like this:

```
<body ng-app="wfMap" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="navigation">
            <div class="navItem" ng-click="show1()">1</div>
            <div class="navItem" ng-click="show2()">2</div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="content1" ng-hide="navIndex!=0" >
                <div id="map1"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="content2" ng-hide="navIndex!=1">
                <div id="map2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

navigation contains two buttons that refer to the to div's with id map1 and map2. Initially map1 is shown and this works as expected. However when I click nav2 map2 shows up only partially. There is space taken by the map and the zoom-in/zoom-out and full-screen buttons for the map are shown. Only the map-data itself is missing. If I go full-screen the missing map-data appears. If I go back from full-screen the map looks as expected... Is there way to have map2 show up correctly?

Comment: I also suffering the same type of problem if you will get the answer please give me also.

Comment: hey, I got a solution.Can you give me plunker So that If I can help you

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. Apparently I don't get it running on plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/EMvTM07F4HiasbOOvVFA?p=preview  ( I think everythink is in place, but angular.js is not loaded correctly)

Comment: In this plunker where is code of map??

Comment: I'm not so familiar with plunkr... I have added a script tag for google maps javascript api. can you be more specific about what you are missing? I am not seeing jquery working.